# How to get the desktop back to normal size and actually fit screen

Tags: xfce, settings

For some reason (probably me accidentally pressing "secret" key combo) my desktop no longer fits screen. Only a portion of it (perhaps 90%) is shown at a time and it scrolls when I move the mouse. That annoys me a lot.

How do I get the screen back to normal again? I'm using xfce 4.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that I accidentally pressed Alt+Scroll Wheel which acts as zoom. Using it again turned the desktop back to normal.